# Python compare screenshot before and after scrolling

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to write a function that can see if mouse scrolling had an effect. For that I take a screenshot of the mouse region, scroll the mouse whell, and after that take another screenshot.

The problem I have is that both screenshots are the same. How could I fix this?

```
import pyautogui
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def scrollHadEffect():
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, x + 50, y + 50))
    pyautogui.scroll(-10)
    im2=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, x + 50, y + 50))
    if im == im2:
        print("SAME")
        im.show()
        im2.show()
    else:
        print("DIFF")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "both screenshots are the same"? Did you save both screenshots to a file, then compare them to see if they were the same? Or is the problem that the screenshots are different, but your program is returning "SAME"?